# Spring cannot resolve JSP view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've got a Tomcat deployment with a single webapp living inside `web/WEB-INF`. Here is the way I'm instantiating the spring container:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>report</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/report-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>report</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `report-servlet.xml` file is found, loaded and parsed properly.

However, my JSP views do not resolve. Here is my resolver:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

I have the root URL mapped to /welcome:

```
<!-- Forwards requests to the "/" resource to the "welcome" view -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="welcome"/>
```

And this view is found and delegated to the `InternalResourceViewResolver` when I request `http://localhost/`, but the .jsp is not found:

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView] (http-11080-1) Rendering view with name 'welcome' with model null and static attributes {}
[org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView] (http-11080-1) Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'welcome'
[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-11080-1) Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@10ea443f
[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-11080-1) DispatcherServlet with name 'report' processing GET request for [//WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp]
[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-11080-1) Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping@4ab83be0] in DispatcherServlet with name 'report'
[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping] (http-11080-1) No handler mapping found for [/WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp]
[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-11080-1) Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@2c1533c8] in DispatcherServlet with name 'report'
[org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (http-11080-1) No handler mapping found for [/WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp]
[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-11080-1) Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@4268cc6] in DispatcherServlet with name 'report'
[org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] (http-11080-1) No handler mapping found for [/WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp]
```

And the contents of WEB-INF/views:

```
# ls -l WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 1.2K 2011-05-24 15:43 WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp
```

Why would the container have no problem finding the Spring xml file containing my beans, but not be able to resolve the directory containing my JSPs?

Comment: what is the url you're using? http://localhost:8080/welcome ? I think you need to make you're url-pattern /*, not /.

Comment: @Kevin: I updated my post to include more information. The root URL is found and mapped to the the resolver, but then that resolver doesn't load my JSP.

Answer (score 3):

Following URL mapping will redirect all the requests to the `report` servlet. But You must not have set up handlers for the JSP files in your dispatcher servlet configurations.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>report</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

To achieve what you want to you must specify the URl pattern that should be redirected to the `report` servlet. This must exclude JSp files.

I will suggest you to specify something like a prefix to your URLs. Only those URLs will be handled by the Spring Dispatcher Servlet. As shown in the below example.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>report</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/report/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Now, all the URlL with `/report/<something>` will be handled by Spring webmvc. This servlet(`report`) will bot be applied to the URLs ending with *.jsp.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to answer my question rather than an edit to the OP or as a comment to an unrelated answer.

Turns out Tomcat was configured improperly. I did not have the JSP servlet configured (or the DefaultServlet for that matter), so the JSP views were not being rendered.